# Why do images appear small in the top left corner in Photoshop CS6 on WIndows 10?

Tags: photoshop-cs6

photoshop cs6 when i open an image it appears on the left top corner and very small. I can't figure out how to center it. Nothing I try moves the image from its place. Can someone please help me?[image: this is exactly what I see]

Comment: Did you check the size of the image you open?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is about specific application operation, not photography.

Comment: Don't be mean to me please, if you have experience, please share. I am running out of sources. Even Adobe closed their door on me. Yes, the image is large 8 mega

Comment: What is reported by "Image->Image Size"?

Comment: the image size reported by photoshop is 20x13 inches

Comment: Try this: Windows->Arrange->Tile. And then you can try with Ctrl-0 to view image to fit window

Comment: yes, it modifies the image within the tiny window, but the window itself stays in place, top left

Comment: Did you try what I suggest above?

Comment: yes I did. the result is that is centers the image within taht tiny box, leaving the box in place, top left

Comment: You can try  Windows->Arrange->Consolidate All to Tabs

Comment: Same thing, it modifies the image, it centers it but leaving the image in the tiny box in the same place

Comment: Did you try to open the image with another image viewer? Can it display the image at full size? if the file is corrupt maybe PS is showing you the embedded thumbnaiL

Comment: @Reyna Have you tried disabling GPU/hardware acceleration?

Comment: I did a bit of research… Adobe won't help you on this because CS6 isn't supported on Win10 at all. If you rely on old, unsupported software you have to be extremely careful before updating your OS. Adobe CS was discontinued in 2013, two years before Win10 was released.

Comment: @Reyna Does this happen with all files you try opening, or just this one? What type of file is it (JPG, TIFF, RAW...)?

Comment: IMHO this question is on topic because it is about a tool used to process/edit actual photographs in order to prepare them for their final displayed form, much the same as darkroom work in the film era.

Answer (score 2):

When you go do Display Settings and select 100% for Scaling of Text, Apps and other elements it should work. I tried at various resolutions and it always gave me your error when selecting anything larger than 100%.

It even worked at my highest resolution setting at 3840x2160 as long as the scaling was 100% (which of course makes the program unusable since everything is very tiny).

Reduce the resolution and scale down to 100% and you should be able to use older CS versions.

I ran into this same issue due to me installing my very old CS5 (which always fit my needs).

Hope this helps.

Billy

Answer (score 1):

Expecting a piece of software discontinued in 2013 to work with an operating system released in 2015 is a bit unrealistic.

You need to either:

- Use an OS for which your software was compatible

OR

- Update your software to a version that works with Windows 10

Comment: I use CS5 on Win 10 without any issues, and I would guess that there are plenty using CS6 as well.

Comment: @Robin Then perhaps you could write an answer to this question explaining how the OP can do so as well?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is caused by the screen resolution - either plug in a second screen with a lower resolution or temporarily change your screen resolution while working in photoshop

Answer (score 0):

I’m running CS5 on windows 11 and had the same issue. Change screen resolution to 1680x1050, open PS and all is good.